# HAML conditional indenting link_to with same content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this condition inside my HAML file but it does not look very pretty :/

```
- if @receiver.type == "Admin"
  = link_to administrator_messages_url, style: "font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;color:#676767;color:#2199e8;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:#fefefe;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;padding:8px 16px 8px 16px;border:0 solid #2199e8;border-radius:3px;border:0 solid #af0000;border-radius:5px;" do
    View Messages
    %i.fa.fa-commenting{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
- else
  = link_to messages_url, style: "font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;color:#676767;color:#2199e8;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:#fefefe;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;padding:8px 16px 8px 16px;border:0 solid #2199e8;border-radius:3px;border:0 solid #af0000;border-radius:5px;" do
    View Messages
    %i.fa.fa-commenting{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
```

How do you prevent repeating the content of the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
= link_to @receiver.type == 'Admin' ? administrator_messages_url : messages_url, style: "font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;color:#676767;color:#2199e8;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:#fefefe;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;padding:8px 16px 8px 16px;border:0 solid #2199e8;border-radius:3px;border:0 solid #af0000;border-radius:5px;" do
  View messages
  %i.fa.fa-commenting{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
```

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to extract that branching from the view. View is not the best place for logic. Even presentation-related logic is best placed elsewhere (a helper, at least).

```
# helper
module ReceiverHelper
  def receiver_url(receiver)
    receiver.type == 'Admin' ? administrator_messages_url : messages_url
  end
end
```

Then in the view

```
  = link_to receiver_url(@receiver), style: "font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;color:#676767;color:#2199e8;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;color:#fefefe;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;padding:8px 16px 8px 16px;border:0 solid #2199e8;border-radius:3px;border:0 solid #af0000;border-radius:5px;" do
    View Messages
    %i.fa.fa-commenting{"aria-hidden" => "true"}
```